# Moving Bitlines takes snapshot of background image with it in panel in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a project where I have to align series of images so for that I use lines created using bitmap. Now user can move and rotate this line in anywhere inside panel which has that image as background. Now I have already tried to make panel double buffered which solves the problem of background snapshot while rotating, but when I move that line it takes a piece of background with it. I also tried to refresh panel but that's not working.
Heres the code:

```
    private bool _rotating;
    private bool _dragging;
    private int _clickX;
    private int _clickY;
    private Point _clickCoords;
    private int _middleX;
    private int _middleY;
    private int _centerX;
    private int _centerY;
    private double _radius;
    private DateTime lastRotate = DateTime.Today;

    public void UpdateCircle(Line l)
    {
        _centerX = (l.EndPoint.X + l.StartPoint.X) / 2 + l.Left;
        _centerY = (l.EndPoint.Y + l.StartPoint.Y) / 2 + l.Top;
        _radius = GetDistance(l.StartPoint.X, l.StartPoint.Y, l.EndPoint.X, l.EndPoint.Y) / 2;
     //   panel5.Refresh();
    }

    public void UpdateMiddle(Line l)
    {
        _middleX = (l.EndPoint.X + l.StartPoint.X) / 2;
        _middleY = (l.EndPoint.Y + l.StartPoint.Y) / 2;
     //   panel5.Refresh();
    }

    public double GetDistance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    }

    public void LineMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var l = (Line)sender;

        if (GetDistance(e.X, e.Y, l.StartPoint.X, l.StartPoint.Y) < 30 ||
            GetDistance(e.X, e.Y, l.EndPoint.X, l.EndPoint.Y) < 30)
        {
            _rotating = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _dragging = true;
           panel5.Refresh();
        }

        _clickX = e.X;
        _clickY = e.Y;

        panel5.Refresh();
        _clickCoords = new Point(l.Left + e.X, l.Top + e.Y);

        UpdateCircle(l);
        UpdateMiddle(l);
   //     panel5.Refresh();
    }

    public void LineMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _rotating = false;
        _dragging = false;
        panel5.Refresh();
    }

    public void LineMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
  //      panel5.Refresh();
        var l = (Line)sender;
        if (_rotating)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastRotate).TotalMilliseconds > 60)
            {
                try
                {
                    var angle = GetAngle(l.Left + e.X, l.Top + e.Y, _centerX, 0, _centerX, _centerY);

                    var newStartPoint = new Point(
                        (int)Math.Round(_middleX + _radius * Math.Sin(angle)),
                        (int)Math.Round(_middleY + _radius * Math.Cos(angle))
                    );

                    var newEndPoint = new Point(2 * _middleX - newStartPoint.X, 2 * _middleY - newStartPoint.Y);

                    l.SetPoints(newStartPoint, newEndPoint);

                    UpdateMiddle(l);

                    lastRotate = DateTime.Now;
                }
                catch
                {
                    //ignored
                }
            }
        }
        else if (_dragging)
        {
            l.Left = l.Left + e.X - _clickX;
            l.Top = l.Top + e.Y - _clickY;
        //    panel5.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public double GetAngle(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int x0, int y0)
    {
        double angle = Math.Atan2(y1 - y0, x1 - x0) - Math.Atan2(y2 - y0, x2 - x0);

        return angle;
    }
```

And heres how I create lines:

```
 bitLine = new Line { LineColor = Color.Red, LineWidth = 2, StartPoint = new Point(x1, y1), EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2) };
             bitLine2 = new Line { LineColor = Color.Red, LineWidth = 2, StartPoint = new Point(x1, y1), EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2) };

            //bitLine.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;

            bitLine.MouseDown += LineMouseDown;
            bitLine.MouseUp += LineMouseUp;
            bitLine.MouseMove += LineMouseMove;

            bitLine2.MouseDown += LineMouseDown;
            bitLine2.MouseUp += LineMouseUp;
            bitLine2.MouseMove += LineMouseMove;

            bitLine2.Click += bitLine2_Click;
            bitLine.Click += bitLine_Click;

            panel5.Controls.Add(bitLine);
            panel5.Controls.Add(bitLine2);

            pb.WireControl(bitLine);
            pb.WireControl(bitLine2);

            bitLine.Location = Program.line1_location;
            bitLine2.Location = Program.line2_location;
```

So please any suggestions will be helpful. I am really stuck in this.

[Here is screenshot of what is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oa4i.png)

Comment: What is the specific issue that you are having?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have added image of what's exactly the problem.